# Is there a way to update the values of the tags from the same type with one statement?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do something like:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0-4].value = "";
```

...instead of using for loop?

Comment: No - you must iterate over the list.

Comment: There is only one way to do it, that is by selecting all of them. Just add .forEach(el => el.value = ' ')